# Scroll HTML at same speed as 3D objects in Fiber/Drei

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a 3D scene that has a bunch of elements that scroll with the page.  I want to add some text in front of them, but I've not found have it match the speed.
[Link to scene in codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-bn53d9?file=/src/Experience.js:0-928)

In the codeSandbox the "hello" text initially starts out in the right position, but as you scroll it quickly gets out of sync with the box.  How can I make the text match movements with any 3d object inside of Scroll?

[image: "hello" should be inside pink box]

```js
import { PerspectiveCamera, Scroll, ScrollControls, Box, Html } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useRef } from 'react'

export default function Experience() {
  const cam = useRef()

  return (
    <>
      <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 13, 10]} ref={cam} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
      <ScrollControls pages={1.8} damping={0.5}>
        <Scroll>
          <pointLight position={[3, 5, 3]} castShadow />
          <Box position={[0, 15, 0]} />
          <Html position={[0, 10, 0]}>hello</Html>
          <Box position={[0, 10, 0]} castShadow material-color="pink" />
          <Box position={[0, 5, 0]} />
          <Box position={[0, 0, 0]} />
          <mesh receiveShadow position-y={-0.5} rotation-x={-Math.PI * 0.5} scale={50}>
            <planeGeometry />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="greenyellow" />
          </mesh>
        </Scroll>
      </ScrollControls>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your html content to scroll as fast as your webgl elements do you can use the Scroll component with the 'html' property. Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-forked-w78oi1

I disabled the camera because it messes with perspective and makes the webgl content scroll in a different speed as it's now further away from the camera than the html content.

Answer (score 0):

when using ScrollControls make sure to structure like this

```
<ScrollControls pages={numberOfPages} damping={scrollBehavior}>
    {/* Canvas contents in here will *not* scroll, but receive useScroll! */}
    
    <Scroll>
        {/* Canvas contents in here will scroll along */}
    </Scroll>
    
    <Scroll html>
        {/* DOM contents in here will scroll along */}
    </Scroll>

</ScrollControls>
```

or if you want something different, use View like in this codesandox

https://codesandbox.io/s/bp6tmc?file=/src/App.js

```
<main ref={container}>
    <h1>Html content here</h1>
    <div ref={tracking} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />

    <Canvas eventSource={container}>
      <View track={tracking}>
        <mesh />
        <OrbitControls />
      </View>
   <Canvas>

</main>
```